# Missing \begin{document} error on using pdfpages package with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

Here is my .tex document and i am compiling to pdf format using `pdflatex a.tex`. It throws an error,

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
```

and after i give `R` to continue, it gives a lot of errors as,

```
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no w in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no [ in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ] in font nullfont!
```

Doc content:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
 On manager end, kafka & zookeeper must be up & running,
#jps
\end{verbatim}
\includepdf{./jps.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The images that i included using `includegraphics` are losing their resolution. So, i exported them as `pdf books` in gimp and using `includepdf` to add them to the pages.

Comment: the letters `newde` do not appear in your sample document, is the warning you show really generated from this document?

Comment: i cut down the tex document to size & updated the issue. the pattern you see in error message is, `newdestlabel[2]lastEntry[1]@@Entry0......` and more characters...

Comment: that's bizarre, does jps.pdf work without error if you look at it in your pdf viewer?

Comment: Not the problem but you just want `\includepdf{jps}`.

Comment: i think, i was really stupid... in india, it was midnight when i posted this.. and i was using `pdflatex a.aux` instead of `pdflatex a.tex`.... thanks David....